# ChartJS - How to always show full level on chartJS

Tags: chart.js

I use Radar ChartJS, I have 5 levels for each position. Here is when my data has 5 levels.
[Showing full 5 level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJIw.png)

However, when my data does not have all 5 levels, the chart only shows the highest level. I wish that when I don't have 5 levels, 5 levels will also be displayed.

[Not Showing full 5 level when data haven't level 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zD5G.png)

My setting

```
scales: {
    r: {
      angleLines: {
        color: '#FFF',
      },
      pointLabels: {
        color: '#FFF', // Color labels
        font: {
          size: 11,
        },
        backdropColor: listColor,
        backdropPadding: "10",
        borderRadius: "15",
        padding: 20,
      },
      grid: {
        circular: true,
        color: "#FFF",
        min: 5,
      },
      beginAtZero: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 1,
        display: false,
      }
    },
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: `scales.r.suggestedMax = 5` or `scales.r.max = 5`?